# Scan other directory from parent folder

Tags: php, scandir

/home/name_a/folder/public_html/index.php script:

```
include_once('/home/name_b/folder/public_html/index.inc.php');
```

index.inc.php script:

```
define("ROOT", __DIR__ ."/");
$pages_dir = 'pages';
include ($page_dir.'/'.filename.php');
$pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
print_r($page);
```

My question is, the include file works fine (/home/name_b/folder/public_html/pages/filename.php) but the scandir looks for /home/name_a/folder/public_html/pages instead. Any idea?

Comment: is it a typo or do you have a syntax error on the second include line

Comment: So what is the problem? If `$pages_dir.'/filename.php'` = `/home/name_b/folder/public_html/pages/filename.php` then essentially `$pages_dir` = `/home/name_b/folder/public_html/pages`. Why the question?

Comment: Because the index file in /name_a? includes another file (index.inc.php) in a different location /name_b/ and I need to scandir of folder in /name_b/folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define pages_dir this way:

```
$pages_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/pages/';
```